# Tplink slows down internet

Tags: router, lan, cable-modem

When I introduce a TL-WR841N Router between my PC and Cable modem, the internet speed drops by 50%.

Cable Modem*  ----- PC     200 Mbps (via speedtest.net)

Cable Modem*  ----Tplink- PC     96 Mbps (via speedtest.net)
   The Tplink -PC cable is less than 10'

- ARRIS Surfboard SB 6141

Cable internet is Comcast Xfinity.

Answer (score 2):

As I was writing I think I found the solution. Posting for posterity.

The [TPLINK specs](http://www.tp-link.com/eg/products/details/TL-WR841N.html#specifications): 300 Mbps wifi, but, oddly, slower on wired.  It's 100Mbps on the WAN/LAN ports.